# how to clean noise character from the concatenating variables in XSLT

Tags: java, xml, variables, xslt

I have this snippet of XSLT code :

```
<xsl:variable name="VulnerabilityURI">
    http://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/detail?vulnId=
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="WeaknessURI">
    http://cwe.mitre.org/data/deﬁnitionsn
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="CVEURI">
    http://www.cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="cweID" select="substring(vuln:cwe/@id,5)" />
<xsl:template match="/*/*">
    <xsl:variable name="cveID" select="vuln:cve-id" />
    <xsl:element name="rdf:Description">
        <xsl:attribute name="rdf:about">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat($VulnerabilityURI, $cveID)" />
        </xsl:attribute>
        <aseg:cveID>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat($CVEURI,$cveID)" />
        </aseg:cveID>
```

And the output comes like the following:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  .....
  .....
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="&#10;&#9;&#9;http://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/detail    
    vulnId=&#10;&#9;CVE-2010-2227">
  <aseg:cveID>
    http://www.cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=
CVE-2010-2227</aseg:cveID>
```

As you can see in this part of result, my desired concatenated variables produced unknown characters

```
  &#10;&#9
```

Any one can help me to figure out the problem ?!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those "noise characters" are a newline and a tab character.  Instead of

```
<xsl:variable name="VulnerabilityURI">
    http://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/detail?vulnId=
</xsl:variable>
```

You could write

```
<xsl:variable 
    name="VulnerabilityURI" 
    select="'http://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/detail?vulnId='" >
```

and then you won't get those characters.

You'll also need to do something similar where you set the CVE ID.

Comment: Don't forget to wrap the select string in quotes (apos) like: `select="'http://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/detail?vulnId='"`. +1